# How can I find a cue vector having many lines on it using opencv?

Tags: opencv

I used the HoughLinesP function and got a lot of lines on the cue

Photo:

[image]

I need to find the cue vector and get something like this :

[image]

What can I use to get this result?

Comment: The easiest way would be to segment by color, select the largest contour, and find the orientation of the minarearect.

Comment: can i use my coordinates and don't touch my image?

Comment: @Slor as beaker said, you can segment objects present on green background and later find contours that resemble a cue